# Can my DIY Arduino be powered with 12V battery via lm2576 switching regulator?

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator, diy

I have lm2576 switching regulator circuit with output constant 5v/3A. Can I use it with a 12V battery and connect it to power my Arduino?

Comment: See [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/) to clear up your apparent confusion about how power supplies are specified. Aside from that you'll also need to know the current capability of your 12 V battery to know whether it can supply enough power for your load.

Comment: @ThePhoton my supply capable current lest than 1.8A... from the links you provide i understand that current depends on the load, right? So, i thinks its ok with this.. im only scaring with the word "constant" before

Comment: As long as the total load doesn't need more than about 18 W (assuming the converter is 85% efficient).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using something like the Arduino Uno that has a power jack, you can just directly connect the 12V to the power jack as the Arduino has an internal voltage regulator (although not a buck converter I believe).

Or you could use the buck converter IC (Lm2576) you mentioned and follow figure 1 exactly from the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf) and place the output through USB or the 5V pin instead.